# Drawing a nested epicycloid

Tags: geometry, fractals

I would like to learn how to draw this kind of pictures (possibly with Mathematica, as it is the only language I would be comfortable to code such a thing in):

[image]

There is something similar on the Wolfram website, involving nested *ipo* cycloids, but I would like to see the math involved in setting up the problem, not just the code.

I have no idea what's the most intelligent way to proceed. Can you help me?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call this a “nested epicycloid”. If this were an epicycloid, then the point to trace would be located on the second-largest circle and rotating *counterclockwise* as that circle rolls along the largest one. For a nested epicycloid, I'd expect the touching point between second and third circle to rotate in this fashion. In your image, however, the third circle moves in a *clockwise* direction around the second. The third makes four turns around the second while that makes one around the first. But I don't see the pattern yet, so I don't know how to iterate that process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, here is how I figure this image was created:

- Each circle has about $\frac5{16}$ the radius of the next larger one, with the largest one at radius $2$.
- Each circle rotates at $4$ times the speed as the next larger one, with respect to a fixed reference orientation. It rotates in the opposite direction.

I can see no “physical” connection between these two quantities, which is a huge difference to the case of the epicycloid, where radius and speed match so that you can imagine one circle rolling along the other.

So you can define

\begin{align*}
r_0 &= 2 & r_{i+1} &= \frac5{16}r_i = 2\left(\frac5{16}\right)^i\\
v_0 &= 1 & v_{i+1} &= -4v_i = (-4)^i
\end{align*}

The center of circle $0$ is at the origin. Each subsequent center rotates around the previous center at a distance which equals the sum of the two corresponding radii, and with a speed which corresponds to the larger circle.

\begin{align*}
x_0 &= 0 & x_{i+1} &= x_i - \left(r_i+r_{i+1}\right)\sin(v_it) \\
x_0 &= 0 & y_{i+1} &= y_i + \left(r_i+r_{i+1}\right)\cos(v_it)
\end{align*}

Now as you iterate $t$ between $0$ and $2\pi$, the centers will move along, and the centers with high index will be pretty good approximations of the limit case.

Here is what the result looks like, with $100{,}000$ points and $10$ levels of recursion. The circles are drawn for $t=0.4$ (not $0.4\pi$). I did this in Sage, but given the description above, you should be able to translate this to Mathematica.

[image: Figure]

And if you wanted to animate this, here is how it should look like, in my opinion:

[image: Animation]

Comment: Awesome awesome awesome!

Comment: @tetrapharmakon: And how many “awsome” do I earn for the added animation? ;-)

Comment: +1 At least one more!